# Finding minimum of interpolated function.

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have a problem I can't figure out. I have created a interpolated function from data using scipy.interpolate.interp2d this gives me a callable function of two variables

```
 def Time_function():

      '''creates a interpolated function of Time depending on
      Cl and Cd using the in and outputs of matlab sim run.
     '''

      return interp2d(import_data()[0], import_data()[1], import_data()[2])
```

Witch works well, however I now want to find the minimum of this function using
scipy.optimize.fmin or mimimize

```
def find_min_time():

     '''finds the min time based on the interpolated function
     '''

     f = Time_function()

     return minimize(f, np.array([1.0, 0.4]))
```

f obviously takes 2 arguments so minimize will need a function (f) and two guesses. However I can't seem to find the correct way to input the initail guesses as I get this error:

```
TypeError: __call__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Anyone know of a solution?

Cheers//

Comment: I don't see where **f** takes 2 arguments; I see no explicit parameters.  Also, I suspect that your problem is that you pass the _value_ of a Time_function call, rather than the function itself.  Try **minimize(Time_function, [1.0, 0.4])** ?

Comment: That returns TypeError: Time_function() takes no arguments (1 given) , wich is strange

Comment: Rats.  Well, if you'd care to supply a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll be happy to work on the mechanics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the help of [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__.html):

```
 |  __call__(self, x, y, dx=0, dy=0, assume_sorted=False)
 |      Interpolate the function.
 |      
 |      Parameters
 |      ----------
 |      x : 1D array
 |          x-coordinates of the mesh on which to interpolate.
 |      y : 1D array
 |          y-coordinates of the mesh on which to interpolate.
```

From the help of [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html):

```
minimize(fun, x0, args=(), method=None, jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, constraints=(), tol=None, callback=None, options=None)
    Minimization of scalar function of one or more variables.
    
    ....
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    fun : callable
        Objective function.
    x0 : ndarray
        Initial guess.
```

So it seems that `interp2d` constructs a function with 2 separate input parameters, but `minimize` tries to stuff in both variables as two components of the same input `ndarray`. You can use a `lambda` to mediate between the two syntaxes:

```
f = Time_function()

return minimize(lambda v: f(v[0],v[1]), np.array([1.0, 0.4]))
```

On a side note, I've found `interp2d` to [give weird results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34656728/5067311) sometimes. You might want to consider using [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html), which doesn't construct an interpolating function for you, but rather computes substituted values for given input points (but you can access the interpolating functions themselves, such as [`LinearNDInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html)). While I'd expect `griddata` to do a better job at interpolating, it would possibly (probably) be slower than substituting into a single interpolating function constructed with `interp2d` (but I'd check regardless).

Comment: That did it! However as you say the interp2d does not seem to me very accurate so I'll try it using griddata! Thanks alot!

Comment: @user5786425 I'm glad I could help. I also find it probable that using `LinearNDInterpolator` will be quicker than many calls to `griddata`, you should check both. Of course if you're not using bilinear interpolation, then another interpolating back-end should be used.