# SciPy interp2D for pairs of coordinates

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm using `scipy.interpolate.interp2d` to create an interpolation function for a surface. I then have two arrays of real data that I want to calculate interpolated points for. If I pass the two arrays to the `interp2d` function I get an array of all the points, not just the pairs of points.

My solution to this is to zip the two arrays into a list of coordinate pairs and pass this to the interpolation function in a loop:

```
f_interp = interpolate.interp2d(X_table, Y_table,Z_table, kind='cubic')

co_ords = zip(X,Y)
out = []
for i in range(len(co_ords)):
    X = co_ords[i][0]
    Y = co_ords[i][1]
    value = f_interp(X,Y)
    out.append(float(value))
```

My question is, is there a better (more elegant, Pythonic?) way of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you can do

```
for Xtmp,Ytmp in zip(X,Y):
    ...
```

in your loop. Or even better, just

```
out = [float(f_interp(XX,YY)) for XX,YY in zip(X,Y)]
```

replacing the loop.

On a different note, [I suggest using `interpolate.griddata`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643642/scipy-interp2d-bisplrep-unexpected-output-when-given-1d-input/34656728#34656728) instead. It tends to behave much better than `interp2d`, and it accepts arbitrary-shaped points as input. As you've seen, `interp2d` interpolators will only return you values on a mesh.

Answer (score 4):

Passing all of your points at once will probably be quite a lot faster than looping over them in Python. You could use [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata):

```
Z = interpolate.griddata((X_table, Y_table), Z_table, (X, Y), method='cubic')
```

or one of the `scipy.interpolate.BivariateSpline` classes, e.g. [`SmoothBivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline):

```
itp = interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline(X_table, Y_table, Z_table)
# NB: choose grid=False to get an (n,) rather than an (n, n) output
Z = itp(X, Y, grid=False)
```

[`CloughTocher2DInterpolator`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.CloughTocher2DInterpolator) also works in a similar fashion, but without the `grid=False` parameter (it always returns a 1D output).

Answer (score 2):

Try *args and tuple packing/unpacking

```
points = zip(X, Y)
out = []
for p in points:
    value = f_interp(*p)
    out.append(float(value))
```

or just

```
points = zip(X, Y)
out = [float(f_interp(*p)) for p in points]
```

or just

```
out = [float(f_interp(*p)) for p in zip(X, Y)]
```

as a side note, the "magic star" allows zip to be its own inverse!

```
points = zip(x, y)
x, y   = zip(*points)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087109/evaluate-the-output-from-scipy-2d-interpolation-along-a-curve) where someone recommends using the internal weights of the interp2d function, I've created the following wrapper which has exactly the same interface as `interp2d` but the interpolant evaluate pairs of inputs and return a numpy array of the same shape of its inputs. The performances should be better than `for` loops or list comprehension, but when evaluated on a grid it will be slightly outperformed by the scipy `interp2d`.

```py
import scipy.interpolate as si
def interp2d_pairs(*args,**kwargs):
    """ Same interface as interp2d but the returned interpolant will evaluate its inputs as pairs of values.
    """
    # Internal function, that evaluates pairs of values, output has the same shape as input
    def interpolant(x,y,f):
        x,y = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)
        return (si.dfitpack.bispeu(f.tck[0], f.tck[1], f.tck[2], f.tck[3], f.tck[4], x.ravel(), y.ravel())[0]).reshape(x.shape)
    # Wrapping the scipy interp2 function to call out interpolant instead
    return lambda x,y: interpolant(x,y,si.interp2d(*args,**kwargs))

# Create the interpolant (same interface as interp2d)
f = interp2d_pairs(X,Y,Z,kind='cubic')
# Evaluate the interpolant on each pairs of x and y values
z=f(x,y)
```