# Evaluate the output from scipy 2D interpolation along a curve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have data `z` sampled from a 2D function `f` at grid points `x, y`, as in `z = f(x, y)`.

It is easy to interpolate `f` with `scipy.interp2d` via `f = interp2d(x, y, z`).

However, evaluating `f(x, y)` returns an entire 2D grid as if I had done

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
f(xx, yy)
```

The behaviour I want is to simply return the values `[f(x[i], y[i]) for i in range(len(x))]`, which I believe is the behaviour for pretty much any other method in numpy.

The reason I want this behaviour is that I'm looking for the path traced out along the surface of `f` over "time" by the pair `(t, u(t))`.

It is also surprising that `np.diag(f(t, u(t)))` differs from `np.array([f(ti, u(ti)) for ti in t])`, so It's not clear to me how to get at the path `f(t, u(t))` from what is returned via `interp2d`.

EDIT: About `diag`, I just thought it seemed we should have `np.diag(f(t, u(t))) == np.array([f(ti, u(ti)) for ti in t])`, but that isn't the case.

Complete example:

```
def f(t, u):
    return (t**2) * np.exp((u**2) / (1 + u**2))

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 250)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, x)

z = f(xx, yy)
f = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z)

print(f(x, y))
print(np.array([f(xi, yi)[0] for xi, yi in zip(x, y)]))
```

I would like the output of both `print` statements to be the same.

Comment: I did not get the last part related to `diag`. Could you, please, provide a workable/reproducible example. Thank you.

Comment: If I do the following after your two print statements: `print(np.allclose(np.diag(f(x, y)), np.array([f(xi, yi)[0] for xi, yi in zip(x, y)])))` I get `True`. So I do not get what is the issue here. Also, I had to replace `y->x` in `f = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z)`.

Answer (score 8):

The method `interp2d` returns an object whose call method expects the x, y vectors to be coordinates of a rectangular grid. And the reason you don't get the desired values from the diagonal of the returned array is that it sorts x, y first.

But there is a workaround, which I also used in [Querying multiple points on a bivariate spline in the B-spline basis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46983476).  After executing

```
import scipy.interpolate as si
f = si.interp2d(x, y, z)
```

evaluate f not by calling it, but by passing its `tck` properties, followed by your x, y coordinates,  to internal `bispeu` method. Like this:

```
print(si.dfitpack.bispeu(f.tck[0], f.tck[1], f.tck[2], f.tck[3], f.tck[4], x, y)[0])
```

The above returns the same as the slow loop

```
print(np.array([f(xi, yi)[0] for xi, yi in zip(x, y)]))
```

#### Explanation

The object `f` is secretly a B-spline of order 1. The spline parameters (knots, coefficients, order) are contained in its `tck` property and can be used directly by lower-order routines to the desired effect.

(Ideally, the call method of `f` would have a Boolean parameter `grid` which we'd set to False to let it know we don't want grid evaluation. Alas, it's not implemented.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `interp2d()` behaves they way it does because that is how the corresponding Fortran function was conceived. The only workaround to this (that I can think of) is to call `f` on pairs of coordinates:

```
[f(*p)[0] for p in zip(x, y)]
```

Comment: Indeed, but I believe this will be much slower.  This also causes problems when I try to pass `f` into an integration routine, since it doesn't play well with mixing scalar and array input.

Comment: That is a trivial problem to solve using lambda: `g = lambda x, y: f(x, y)[0]` and pass `g`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on user6655984's suggestion, I've posted the following wrapper function in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360756/scipy-interp2d-for-pairs-of-coordinates):

```py
import scipy.interpolate as si
def interp2d_pairs(*args,**kwargs):
    """ Same interface as interp2d but the returned interpolant will evaluate its inputs as pairs of values.
    """
    # Internal function, that evaluates pairs of values, output has the same shape as input
    def interpolant(x,y,f):
        x,y = np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)
        return (si.dfitpack.bispeu(f.tck[0], f.tck[1], f.tck[2], f.tck[3], f.tck[4], x.ravel(), y.ravel())[0]).reshape(x.shape)
    # Wrapping the scipy interp2 function to call out interpolant instead
    return lambda x,y: interpolant(x,y,si.interp2d(*args,**kwargs))

# Create the interpolant (same interface as interp2d)
f = interp2d_pairs(X,Y,Z,kind='cubic')
# Evaluate the interpolant on each pairs of x and y values
z=f(x,y)
```