# Extracting a vector of values from interp2d

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm making the following call to [interp2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)

```
f = interpolate.interp2d(im_xs, im_ys, I)
```

Here are the dimensions of each of the arguments

`im_xs`: (120, )

`im_ys`: (120, )

`I`: (120, 160)

I would like to pass `f` a vector of `x` values and a vector of `y` values and I expect to get a single dimension output vector containing `len(x) == len(y)` interpolated values.

```
values = f(rr, cc)
```

where

`rr`: (1332, )

`cc`: (1332, )

However...

`values`: (1332, 1332)

I expected to just get a vector of `1332` values because I want to interpolate exactly `1332` coordinates on a 2D grid `I`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate the output from scipy 2D interpolation along a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087109/evaluate-the-output-from-scipy-2d-interpolation-along-a-curve)

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error when I run the correct answer.

`ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (0,)`

Comment: I tested it again, in SciPy 1.1.0 and 0.19.1. Worked fine. A complete example: `import scipy.interpolate as si;
import numpy as np;
x = np.arange(120)/2;
y = np.arange(120)/3;
z = np.add.outer(np.sin(x), np.cos(y));
f = si.interp2d(x, y, z);
xx = np.random.uniform(60, size=100);
yy = np.random.uniform(40, size=100);
si.dfitpack.bispeu(f.tck[0], f.tck[1], f.tck[2], f.tck[3], f.tck[4], xx, yy)[0]`