# 1D interpolation ... of 2D grids

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation

I know this can be quite confusing, so please let me know if this explanation needs some editing.

Let's say that I have input data in this format:

for a given pressure `p_0` --> 2x2 grid of temperatures (`T_0`) that refer to this pressure value

for a given pressure `p_1` --> 2x2 grid of temperatures (`T_1`) that refer to this pressure value

```
p_0 = 0
T_0 = np.array([[1, 4], [3, 2]])

p_1 = 1
T_1 = np.array([[1, 6], [4, 4]])

p = np.array([p_0, p_1])
T = np.array([T_0, T_1])
```

Now, I am given a 2x2 grid of new pressure values

```
p_target = np.array([[0.1, 0.4], [0.3, 0.2]])
```

and I would like to get a 2x2 grid of interpolated temperatures values, using the input data.

The way I'm doing this is for each point of the grid, I build an interpolation function and then I use it to get the new interpolated temperature value for that grid point:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

T_new = np.empty(p_target.shape)

for ix,iy in np.ndindex(p_target.shape):
    f = interp1d(p, T[:,ix,iy])
    T_new[ix,iy] = f(p_target[ix,iy])

T_new

array([[1. , 4.8],
       [3.3, 2.4]])
```

As it's easy to guess, this is quite slow for large arrays, and it seems to be quite against the numpy way of doing things.

EDIT: I'm using `interp1d` also because it allows for extrapolation too, which is an option I'd like to keep.

Comment: What is T? Can you show us a few more input-output pairs?

Comment: Could you tell us about the format of this variables. If I do understand you have one feature (pressure) and 4 targets (temperatures) and you want to linearly interpolate new temperatures from pressure using the two points provided as `p` and `T`. And your main issue is a performance issue. Have I got it properly?

Comment: Could you provide us a different sized `p_target` to understand what would be a greater matrix. Also, is that mandatory to keep this structure? I have the feeling things are more complicated than it needs to.

Comment: @hkchengrex T represents the temperature. I have edited the code to make the first part clearer and less ambiguous. I'm not sure about what you mean by the input-output pairs. If the interpolation function is `f(x,y)` then `x->p`, `y->T`, and my `x_new` is `p_target`, since the goal is to run `f(x_new)`.


@jlandercy I think you got it right. The performance problem begins when instead of having 2x2 matrixes for `T_0`, `T_1` and `p_target` you have something much larger like 1000x1000. Not sure about what you mean by "structure", honestly all I care about is to get to that final result

Comment: Oh and in the real life problem `len(p)` is much larger too

Comment: In you actual problem, do you have more than two `T` input values (and if so, are those evenly spaces between a [0, 1] domain)? Do you need to do this for a single `p_target` at a time, or potentially for many?

Comment: @jdehesa yes more than two `T`, no not evenly spaced, potentially for many `p_target`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just compute the interpolation yourself. Here I assume you have more than two `T` values and that `p` is not necessarily evenly-spaced. Also, the code assumes a you have several `p_target` values, but obviously works for just a single one.

```py
import numpy as np

p_0 = 0
T_0 = np.array([[1., 4.], [3., 2.]])
p_1 = 1
T_1 = np.array([[1., 6.], [4., 4.]])
p = np.array([p_0, p_1])
T = np.array([T_0, T_1])
p_target = np.array([[0.1, 0.4], [0.3, 0.2]])
# Assume you may have several of p_target values
p_target = np.expand_dims(p_target, 0)

# Find the base index for each interpolated value (assume p is sorted)
idx_0 = (np.searchsorted(p, p_target) - 1).clip(0, len(p) - 2)
# And the next index
idx_1 = idx_0 + 1
# Get p values for each interpolated value
a = p[idx_0]
b = p[idx_1]
# Compute interpolation factor
alpha = ((p_target - a) / (b - a)).clip(0, 1)
# Get interpolation values
v_0 = np.take_along_axis(T, idx_0, axis=0)
v_1 = np.take_along_axis(T, idx_1, axis=0)
# Compute interpolation
out = (1 - alpha) * v_0 + alpha * v_1
print(out)
# [[[1.  4.8]
#   [3.3 2.4]]]
```

EDIT: If you want linear extrapolation, simply do not clip the `alpha` values:

```py
alpha = ((p_target - a) / (b - a))
```

Comment: is this a method that uses only the two points that are "neighbors" of the point where we want to interpolate to ? 
I'm assuming this then wouldn't work for extrapolation (I'll add that I need this in my post).
For the interpolation part, is this going to be faster than my original method ?

Comment: @duff18 Yes, this interpolates each point in the grid using the `T` value above and below. `p_target` values out of the range of `p` are set to the lowest or highest corresponding `T` value, by extrapolating you mean actually using the "slope" with respect to the previous `T` to linearly continue the trend outside of the bounds? For interpolation, this should be faster than looping, although I haven't tested the performance.

Comment: For the extrapolation, yes, I'm guessing that'd be the easiest way of doing things. Thanks, I'll then try to see how this method's speed compares

Comment: @duff18 Actually for linear extrapolation you just have to leave the `alpha` values unclipped, I added that to the answer.

Comment: This means that in case the user can not know beforehand whether he needs to interpolate or extrapolate, the code should be able to figure out that itself, right ?

Comment: @duff18 Well you can tweak the code to either clip the alpha, not clip it or raise an error if it goes out of [0, 1], depending on what you need.

Comment: then it seems that for both interpolation and extrapolation one can simply use a standard interpolation formula such as `out = v_0 + (v_1 - v_0)/(b - a)*(p_target - a)`,  which it's also slightly faster according to my test

Answer (score 1):

I added some parameters for the dimensions; from your choice of `n_x = n_y = n_p = 2`, the dependencies were not that clear.

```py
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d, interp2d, dfitpack

n_x = 30
n_y = 40
n_p = 50
T = np.random.random((n_p, n_x, n_y)) * 100
p = np.random.random(n_p)
p[np.argmin(p)] = 0
p[np.argmax(p)] = 1
p_target = np.random.random((n_x, n_y))

T_new = np.empty(p_target.shape)

for ix, iy in np.ndindex(p_target.shape):
    f = interp1d(p, T[:, ix, iy])
    T_new[ix, iy] = f(p_target[ix, iy])
```

Than a word to your modelling. If I understood correctly you want `temperature_xy = fun_xy(pressure)`, a separate function for each coordinate on your spatial grid.
Another option might be to include the spatial components in a combined function `temperature_xy = fun(pressure, x, y)`. For the second approach have look at [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html).

You can rearrange the first approach to make it work with `interp2d()`.
For this the first dimension is the pressure `x=pressure` and the second dimension represents the combined spatial dimensions `y=product(x, y)`.
To make this behave as `n_x * n_y` independent interpolations of the pressure values, I just use the same dummy values 0, 1, 2... for the spatial components both when creating the interpolation and when evaluating it.
Because the evaluation of `interp2d()` normaly only works on grid coordinates,
I used the method provided by [user6655984](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233198/7570817) to evaluate the function only on a specific set of points.

```py
def evaluate_interp2d(f, x, y):
    """https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233198/7570817"""
    return dfitpack.bispeu(f.tck[0], f.tck[1], f.tck[2], f.tck[3], f.tck[4], x, y)[0]

f2 = interp2d(x=p, y=np.arange(n_x*n_y), z=T.reshape(n_p, n_x*n_y).T)

T_new2 = evaluate_interp2d(f=f2, x=p_target.ravel(), y=np.arange(n_x*n_y))
T_new2 = T_new2.reshape(n_x, n_y)

print(np.allclose(T_new, T_new2))
# True
```

With those settings I get a time improvement of almost `10x`. But if you use even larger values, like `n_x=n_y=1000` the memory usage of this *custom interp2d* approach grows too large and you iterative approach wins.

```
# np=50
#    nx*ny      1e2      1e4      1e5      1e6
# interp1d  0.0056s  0.3420s  3.4133s  33.390s
# interp2d  0.0004s  0.0388s  2.0954s  191.66s
```

With this knowledge you could loop over a big `1000x1000` grid and process `100x100` pieces sequentially, then you would end up at around 3sec instead of 30sec.

```py
def interpolate2d_flat(p, p_target_flat, T_flat):
    n_p, n_xy = T_flat.shape
    f2 = interp2d(x=p, y=np.arange(n_xy), z=T_flat.T)
    return evaluate_interp2d(f=f2, x=p_target_flat, y=np.arange(n_xy))


n_splits = n_x * n_y // 1000  # So each patch has size n_p*1000, can be changed 

# Flatten and split the spatial dimensions
T_flat_s = np.array_split(T.reshape(n_p, n_x*n_y), n_splits, axis=1)
p_target_flat_s = np.array_split(p_target.ravel(), n_splits, axis=0)

# Loop over the patches
T_new_flat = np.concatenate([interpolate2d_flat(p=p, p_target_flat=ptf, T_flat=Tf)
                             for (ptf, Tf) in zip(p_target_flat_s, T_flat_s)])
T_new2 = T_new_flat.reshape(n_x, n_y)
```

Comment: Thanks ! `griddata` doesn't seem to support `fill_value = “extrapolate”` which is something I wanted to have the option to use. As for the `interp2d` approach, it's a big punch in the eye for readability but I'd have used it if it could guarantee a substantial speed-up but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It's great you found out that one can save time by using the `interp1d` approach sequentially though. The price to pay is to "unpack" the big array, but it sounds like it's worth it

Comment: You mean using the `interp2d` approach iteratively? I updated my answer to include this splitting, I got a speed improvement of almost 20x, so maybe it is worth it for you. Hope I could help.

Comment: Yes, `interp2d`, my bad