# Unable to interprete MATLAB interp2d in Python scipy.interp

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scipy

The following code is just to understand the context. My question doesn't require much understanding of this. It need a simple translation of one line of MATLAB code in to Python.

```
us = np.linspace(-(1023)/2,(1023)/2,1024)
vs = np.linspace(-(1023)/2,(1023)/2,1024)
uu,vv = np.meshgrid(-us,vs)
pu = ((((rx*SDD)/(ry+SOD))+us[0])/(-du))+1

xs = np.linspace(-(360-1)/2,(nx-1)/2,360)
ys = np.linspace(-(360-1)/2,(ny-1)/2,360)
zs = np.linspace(-(360-1)/2,(ny-1)/2,360)

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(xs,ys)

angle_rad = np.linspace(0,359,360)
angle_rad = angle_rad*np.pi/180

for i in range(0,360) :
    vol = np.zeros((360,360,360))
    rx = xx*np.cos(angle_rad[i]-np.pi/2) + yy*np.sin(angle_rad[i]-np.pi/2)
    ry = -xx*np.sin(angle_rad[i]-np.pi/2) + yy*np.cos(angle_rad[i]-np.pi/2)
    pu = ((((rx*370)/(ry+9))+us[0])/(-51.2/1024))+1

    for iz in range(0,360) :
        pv = ((((zs[iz]*370)/(ry+9))-vs[0])/(51.2/1024)) +1
```

So after this step the code should do interpolation and in MATLAB it's like this:

```
vol(:,:,iz) = interp2(uu,vv ,proj',pu,pv,'linear'); This is in MATLAB
```

My proj, uu and vv are (1024,1024) and pu, pv are (360,360). I need to convert the above line to Python. I tried using scipy.interpolate but it gives the following errors on trying these :

```
vol[:,:,iz] = Ratio*(interp2d(uu,vv,proj,pu,pv,'cubic'))
```

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

```
vol[:,:,iz] = Ratio*(interp2d(uu,vv,proj,'cubic'))
```

OverflowError: Too many data points to interpolate

```
vol[:,:,iz] = Ratio*(interp2d(proj,pu,pv,'cubic'))
```

ValueError: x and y must have equal lengths for non rectangular grid

```
vol[:,:,iz] = Ratio*(interp2d(pu,pv,proj,'cubic'))
```

ValueError: Invalid length for input z for non rectangular grid

I have read all the scipy.interpolate documentations and none seemed to help. Could anyone figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Read http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html and look at the example at the bottom of the page. Rather than just reading it, open a Python console and repeat each of the steps and try printing the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem on a wide scale is that you're looking at the documentation but you're not trying to understand it. If you're using a specific function `interp2d` in the module `scipy.interpolate`, then [look at the function's documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html), as [@pv also suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955658/unable-to-interprete-matlab-interp2d-in-python-scipy-interp#comment59571307_35955658). The fact that you're throwing the arguments all around the place clearly demonstrates that you're trying to use a function based on guesswork. It won't work: a function was implemented with a given syntax, and it will only work like that.

So look at the function's signature:

> class scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='linear', copy=True, bounds_error=False, fill_value=nan)

The meaning of the parameters is explained afterwards. You can clearly see that there are 3 mandatory parameters: `x`, `y`, `z`. No other array-valued inputs are allowed This is because `interp2d` only constructs an interpolating *function*, which you should then use to compute the interpolated values on a mesh (unlike MATLAB, where `interp2d` gives you the interpolated values directly). So you can call

```
myfun = interp2(uu,vv,proj,'linear')
```

to get an interpolating *function*. You can then substitute at the given values, but note that the function `myfun` will expect 1d input, and it will construct a mesh internally. So assuming that your output mesh is constructed as

```
puu,puv = np.meshgrid(puu_vec,puv_vec)
```

(which is probably not the case, but I'll get back to this later), you need

```
vol[:,:,iz] = Ratio*myfun(puu_vec,puv_vec)
```

to obtain the output you need.

However, there are some important points you should note.

1. In MATLAB you have `interp2d(uu,vv,proj',...)`, but make sure that for `scipy` the elements of `uu`, `vv`, and `proj` are in the same order. To be on the safe side: in case of an asymmetric mesh size, the shape of `uu`, `vv` and `proj` should all be the same.
2. In MATLAB you're using `'linear'` interpolation, while in python you're using `'cubic'`. I'm not sure this is really what you want, if you're porting your code to a new language.
3. It seems to me that your output mesh is not defined by a rectangular grid as if from `meshgrid`, which suggests that [`interp2d` might not be suitable for your case](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__). Anyway, [I've had some odd experiences with `interp2d`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34656728/5067311), and I wouldn't trust it. So if it's not suitable for your expected output, I'd strongly suggest using [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) instead. This function gives you interpolated points directly: I suggest that you try to figure out its use based on the manual:) My linked answer can also help. You can set the kind of interpolation in the same way, but your output can be any set of scattered points if you like.

Comment: I tried this. f = interp2d(uu,vv,proj,'cubic')
    vol[:,:,iz] = Ratio*f(pu,pv) But it says OverflowError: Too many data points to interpolate. My pu and pv are (360,360) and if the inputs are supposed to be 1-D I tried pu=pu.reshape(pu.size) and same for pv to make it 1-D. But it still gives the same overflow error.

Comment: @PrakritiKumari read my example code carefully. It's not the *shape* that is the problem, but the structure of the points themselves. If your input points would be `[0,0]`, `[0,1]`, `[1,0]`, `[1,1]`, then your `pu` and `pv` are something like `[[0,0],[1,1]]` and `[[0,1],[0,1]]` (or the other way around). If you want to interpolate over these 2x2 points, you have to give only the two 2-element vectors to the interpolator: `f([0,1],[0,1])`. So the same vectors go into `f()` that can be used to generate your mesh with `meshgrid`.

Comment: This is why I'm saying that if your points are not on a grid, you can't use `interp2d`. Or at least you're way better off with `griddata`. Do you understand now?